# OLE DB Provider and openrecordset

Tags: sql-server-2005

With SQL Server 2005 using SSMS, when I run this:

SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\TestIDs.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')

And get this:

The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.

Is it referring to the server or my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it reffers to the server.